# Tweaking Eloquent relations – how to get N related models per parent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

How to get 2 latest comments of each post?
I use laravel 5.2 and Postgres

My comments table

```
+-----+---------------------+---------+
| id  | created_at          | post_id |
+-----+---------------------+---------+
| 344 | 2014-08-17 21:25:46 |       1 |
| 320 | 2014-08-17 21:25:45 |       1 |
|   4 | 2014-08-17 21:25:26 |       1 |
|  72 | 2014-08-17 21:25:29 |       1 |
| 158 | 2014-08-17 21:25:37 |       2 |
| 423 | 2014-08-17 21:25:50 |       2 |
|  59 | 2014-08-17 21:25:29 |       2 |
| 227 | 2014-08-17 21:25:40 |       2 |
| 308 | 2014-08-17 21:25:45 |       3 |
|  34 | 2014-08-17 21:25:28 |       3 |
+-----+---------------------+---------+
```

My posts table

```
+-----+---------------------+---------+
| id  | created_at          | title   |
+-----+---------------------+---------+
| 1   | 2014-08-17 21:25:46 |       a |
| 2   | 2014-08-17 21:25:45 |       b |
| 3   | 2014-08-17 21:25:26 |       c |
+-----+---------------------+---------+
```

I want to get all posts with latest 2 comments. How can I do this with Eloquent.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You need to define additional relation in your **Post** model that will return **2 latest comments**:

```
class Post extends Model {
  public function latest_comments() {
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)->take(2)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
  }
}
```

Now, for every post, you can access its 2 latest comments with **$post->latest_comments**;

Comment: This code will display only for 2 latest comments for all posts, but I want 2 latest comments for each post. Do you have any idea?

Comment: With this code each post will hold its 2 latest comments, not 2 latest comments for all posts

Comment: I use `Post::with('latest_comments')->get()` then I get only 2 latest comments with 3 posts

Comment: Does each post have the same comments?

Comment: No sir! One comment belongs to only one post. And only first post has 2 comments and others posts are not

Comment: I don't think I get it. The code above will give you for every post 2 latest comments for that particular post, isn't that what you need?

Comment: Do you mean every post has 2 comments?

Comment: No, I mean you'll get 2 latest comments or less for every post

Comment: But I want every post with 2 latest comments when I use `Post::with('latest_comments')->get()`

Comment: 2 latest comments for each of the posts or 2 latest comments in general?

Comment: 2 latest comments for each of the posts

Comment: And what are you getting? The code above will give you exactly what you asked for